# Worked out FFT example per Hand

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

Can anyone please show me the worked out example of FFT. Suppose for the signal

x = (1/2, 1/4, 0, 1/4 , 1/2, 1/4, 0, 1/4).

What I think I know:

First I need to do the bit reversing, I get

x = (1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4)

Next step, I need to calculate butterflies but I don't understand the steps. Any help will be appreciated.

Is this the right stackexchange for the question? Should I go to dsp.stackexchange instead??

Comment: what you want to understand is the FFT algorithm or the discrete Fourier transform ? and forget butterflies (only electronic engineers care of that..), read first the mathematical description.

Comment: I want to understand the FFT algorithm, with an example of course.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley–Tukey_FFT_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley–Tukey_FFT_algorithm)